# Why does this function always return 0

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, stored-functions

I don't know why this function always returns 0

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QTYDEPOT(
    p_org_id     IN NUMBER,
    p_product_id IN NUMBER,
    p_datefrom   IN DATE,
    p_dateto     IN DATE)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  qty NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C_InvoiceLine.qtyinvoiced), 0)
  INTO qty
  FROM C_InvoiceLine
  INNER JOIN C_invoice
  ON (c_invoiceline.C_INVOICE_ID = c_invoice.C_INVOICE_ID)
  INNER JOIN C_BPartner
  ON (c_invoice.C_BPARTNER_ID   = c_bpartner.C_BPARTNER_ID)
  WHERE C_BPartner.ISSALESREP   = 'N'
  AND C_BPartner.ISEMPLOYEE     = 'N'
  AND c_bpartner.ISCUSTOMER     = 'Y'
  AND c_invoiceline.AD_org_id   = p_org_id
  AND c_invoiceline.m_product_id= p_product_id
  AND c_invoice.DateInvoiced BETWEEN p_datefrom AND p_dateto;
  RETURN qty ;
END;
```

P.S : if I remove the date part of the close `where`

```
c_invoice.DateInvoiced BETWEEN p_datefrom AND p_dateto;
```

The function returns the real values.

I call it like this

```
SELECT  
   ..
   QTYDEPOT( 1000000, p.m_product_id,'7/7/2014','24/7/2014') as qtyDepot
```

Comment: Well do you have any matching records in the tables, for the values and dates you're passing in? I'd usually suspect a date format issue as you're passing string and relying in implicit conversion but that would error in this case (as there is no month 24).

Comment: What happens if you run the same query by hand outside the function?

Comment: I guess you are using British date format.  To be sure that the date is being read correctly, I would recommend using '24/Jul/2014' or ISO format '2014-07-24'.

Comment: you need to evalute this query first select * FROM C_InvoiceLine
  INNER JOIN C_invoice
  ON (c_invoiceline.C_INVOICE_ID = c_invoice.C_INVOICE_ID)
  INNER JOIN C_BPartner
  ON (c_invoice.C_BPARTNER_ID   = c_bpartner.C_BPARTNER_ID)
  WHERE C_BPartner.ISSALESREP   = 'N'
  AND C_BPartner.ISEMPLOYEE     = 'N'
  AND c_bpartner.ISCUSTOMER     = 'Y'
  AND c_invoiceline.AD_org_id   = p_org_id
  AND c_invoiceline.m_product_id= p_product_id
  AND c_invoice.DateInvoiced BETWEEN p_datefrom AND p_dateto;
  RETURN qty ;you should get records for above query..check joins and where clause.

Comment: i found it problrmr iin the call of date it must be like this QTYDEPOT( 1000000, p.m_product_id,'7/7/14','24/7/14') as qtyDepot

Comment: @AlexPoole got the point. Using implicit string to date conversion is asking for the problems. Instead always use `to_date` with format model: `to_date('2014-07-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. More verbose but crystal clear.

Comment: I suggest that you use the `TO_DATE` function to convert your strings into DATE values - for example, `TO_DATE('24/7/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. Don't count on Oracle converting a character string directly - how this is done will vary depending on how the database is set up. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have problems with DATE manipulation. I would suggest you to try calling your function like this :

```
SELECT  
   ..
   QTYDEPOT( 1000000, p.m_product_id,DATE('2014-07-07'),DATE('2014-07-24')) as qtyDepot
```

AS you can see, Oracle standard format is `'yyyy-mm-dd'` I don't know if `DATE(...)` is needed, but I use to manipulate `DATE` like this: code is clearer.

Comment: I don't think `DATE` can be used as shown above. Perhaps the intent was to use the `TO_DATE` function, as in: `TO_DATE('2014-07-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  
   ..
   QTYDEPOT( 1000000, p.m_product_id,to_date('7/7/2014','dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('24/7/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')) as qtyDepot
```

you have to specify the date format you are passing to the function,

hope this helps!